# Centralizer of a pseudo-Anosov element

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

What is the centralizer of a pseudo-Anosov element in the mapping class group of an orientable punctured surface? Is it cyclic? If so, where can I find a proof?

Answer (score 2):

See [McCarthy's paper](http://www.math.msu.edu/~mccarthy/publications/normcent.pdf) And here are some more characters.

Comment: In more detail, the centralizer is virtually cyclic but is not cyclic in general.